# XACML Policy definition Resource attribute with a Wildcard option

Tags: wildcard, xacml

How to define XACML Policy that checks something like  table name like 'EMPL%'

Do I have to use RegEx for that?

Answer (score 2):

There are several string functions you could use.

In the XACML 3.0 specification (http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-cs-01-en.pdf), you can use:

- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-ends-with
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-starts-with
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:string-contains
- urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match

The latter is what you would want to use. See section *A.3.13 Regular-expression-based functions* for more information.